# Only add an image to an embed if there is an attachment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a command for quoting. The command takes in a message ID and sends an embed that contains that message's author, content, time, etc. One thing it doesn't include is any attachments in the message.

I added an "image:" field to the embed, and this works fine IF the quoted message has an attachment. If the message DOESN'T have any attachment, then the embed doesn't send.

I believe this is because it's searching for an attachment to add as an image to the embed, but it can't find one, so it errors out.

Here's what I had:

```js
url: messagea.attachments.first().url
```

Here's a solution I've tried (this has the exact same problem):

```js
url: messagea.attachments === null ? null : messagea.attachments.first().url
```

How can I make it so the embed only includes an image IF there is an attachment?

Answer (score 0):

One trick you can use to determine whether the attachment is an image is using the [`MessageAttachment.height`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=height) property, since it will exist only if the attachments is an image or video.

```js
let attachment = message.attachments.first() // Get the first attachment

// If the attachment exists and has an height...
if (attachment && typeof attachment.height == 'number') {
  let { url } = attachment // ...get the URL
  // You can now send your embed
} // else: do nothing
```

Comment: I need to add this to a .then() method. How would I set a variable in a .then() method? Right now I have:

```.then(messagea => message.channel.send({embed: {``` and then my embed.

Comment: In the same way, you can use `var`, `let` and `const` as usual, even if you're are inside the `then` callback